# Updating multiple rows by creating sp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table A which contain

```
Message id   pktextmesag   xml         date tim 
    1          asgk        xml data    tim ddate 
    2          sjsjsj
```

I am inserting only `message id` and `pktextmessag` to a temp table

And I have a table B

I am checking if the `message id` in table A exists in table B or not. If it exists, I am replaying to 2 else I will replay to 1 (replayid is a column in table B).

So in this case the temp table have 10 message id in which 5 was exist in table b and remaining 5 was not available in table B. So for first 5 I have to reply as 1 and remaining 5 I have to reply as 2

How do I do this? Please anyone rep

Comment: Please saw your TSQL code thx

Comment: Can you write your SQL code or explain yourself better with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join from table A to table B...if a row is matched, then the record exists in B and you'll have a populated b.id, if it's not matched b.id will be null.  Use case to translate that:

```
select id, case when b.id is null then 1 else 2 end as reply
from a
left join b on a.id = b.id
```

If this answer isn't what you're going for...I tried, please clarify your question...include code and sample data